# Where returns object reference not set to an instance of object

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm new to Linq. I've 2 tables Table 1 and Table 2. They are related by `Id1`.

```
Table 1                   Table2
-------                   ------
  Id1                      Id2 RId1 (reference key from TAble 1)
   1                       1    1
                           2    1
   2                       3    2
                           4    2
                           5    Null
   3                       6    .
   .                       7    .
   .
```

When I use the `Where` clause to query data from table 2, I get error `Object reference not set to an instance of object`

`var result = db.Table2.Where(i => i.Rid1 == 1);`

Even this code doesn't help
`if (result != null)`

Please help me.

Comment: Where exactly do you get this error? On the line you quoted, or on a different line? With the above query, result will never be null, but result may well have no elements: You can check with `if (result.Any())`

Comment: I get error on the Where clause

Comment: You could try viewing the whole table: `var test1 = db.Table2.ToList(); var test2 = db.Table2.Select(i=>i.Rid1).ToList();`, then step into the debugger and view the contents of these variables. Anything odd there?

Answer (score 0):

In this case it appears that Rid1 is a nullable. Comparing a null against an integer may result in that error. Try changing it to the following:

```
db.Table2.Where(i => i.Rid1.GetValueOrDefault(0) == 1);
```